# Sphinx Converting Plain Old Index to Real-Time (RT) Index

Tags: php, mysql, sql, indexing, sphinx

Now first i have been experimenting with sphinx few days so im newbie to sphinx.

I integrated sphinx search (plain) which is working fine.
But until recently i found that RT is a better option to go for.

**PLAIN OL' Sphinx**

```
source people
{
  type          = mysql

  sql_host      = localhost
  sql_user      = root
  sql_pass      = 
  sql_db        = test
  sql_port      = 3306 # optional, default is 3306 
 
 sql_query     = SELECT id, name FROM people
 sql_field_string = name
 sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM people WHERE id=$id
}

index people
{
  source            = people 
  ...
}

searchd
{
  listen            = 9312   # Port to listen on
   ....
}
```

**RT Sphinx**

```
index people
{
  type = rt
  rt_field = name
  ...  
}
searchd
{
  listen            = 9312   # Port to listen 
  listen = 9306:mysql41
  workers = threads
  ...
}
```

Now if i query something like (I'm using *PHP* and [**This Sphinx API (GitHub)**](https://github.com/romainneutron/Sphinx-Search-API-PHP-Client/blob/master/sphinxapi.php) ) this ...

```
  require_once('sphinxapi.php');
  $cl = new SphinxClient();
  $cl->SetServer( "localhost", 9312 ); 
  $cl->SetMatchMode( SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED  );   
  $qq = "Mike";
  $result = $cl->Query('@name "'.$qq.'"','people'); 
  var_dump($result);
```

- **In Plain-Ol**' - I get **5** Hits (coz i have 5 people named Mike_xxx)(*its working*)
- **In RT** - I get **0** Hits (not working)

P.S  - I inserted some people's name in my mysql using *phpmyadmin* after creating RT index . But still RT index has 0 Hits.

### **UPDATE 2**

As guided by @barryhunter I thought of taking the advantage of `ATTACH` because i dont feel like doing the queries (inserts,updates,deletes) twice for MySQL and SphinxQL Seperately.

After a little research i came across this [Ivinco Blog post](https://www.ivinco.com/blog/converting-sphinx-original-indexes-to-real-time-indexes/) and i modified my `.conf` to this

**New RT Sphinx Conf**

```
source people
{
  type          = mysql

  sql_host      = localhost
  sql_user      = root
  sql_pass      = 
  sql_db        = test
  sql_port      = 3306 # optional, default is 3306 

 sql_query     = SELECT id, name FROM people
 sql_field_string = name
 sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM people WHERE id=$id
}

index people
{
  source            = people 
  ...
} 

index people_rt
{
  type = rt
  rt_field = name
  ...  
}
source people_attach
{ 
    ... 
    sql_query       = select 1 from people_rt
    sql_query_post = ATTACH INDEX people TO RTINDEX people_rt
}
index people_attach
{
    source          = people_attach
}

searchd
{
  listen            = 9312   # Port to listen 
  listen = 9306:mysql41
  workers = threads
  ...
}
```

Now I ran these commands in my Terminal(Ubuntu)

**P.S** - *All the Previous index,pids were deleted .*

```
sudo indexer -c /path/to/xxx.conf people
sudo indexer -c /path/to/xxx.conf people_attach

#ERROR: index 'people_attach': sql_query: No database selected (DSN=mysql://root:***@localhost:9306/)

sudo searchd 

#WARNING: index 'people_attach': preload: failed to open /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/people_attach.sph: No such file or directory; NOT SERVING
```

Now I am getting 5 hits for Mike. But If i Insert/Update anything in mysql(using PHPMyAdmin/PHP script) the RT is not updating ?

Wasn't that the main purpose of attach?

Comment: You appear to have defined the RT index. But did you actully add any data to it?? (eg via INSERT, or even ATTACH ?)

Comment: (Inserting into the RT index, not inserting into database. RT indexes have no connection to a database)

Comment: No Havent inserted anything in RT index. @barryhunter . if RT index have no connection to a database , then do I have to insert the data twice ? Once in DB(MySQL) and Once  in Sphinx ? If YES then , since I'm using **PHP** i do `mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ....");` how to insert into RT index using PHP  ?

Comment: @barryhunter say i have to insert `id = 10,name = 'MIKE_445'` in the sphinx RT index i just created using PHP how do i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to insert data twice yes. (although as mentioned can use ATTACH RT index, to convert a disk index to a RT index. intended to 'kickstart' a big index, indexer can build a large index quite effiently. Once built convert the index to RT, then can continue to update it directly)

The idea is the application can update sphinx index directly, so it can itself ensure the index is uptodate. (a disk index with indexer, is typically recreatd on a schedule, so typically lags)

To update a RT index need to use SphinxQL. Cant use the SphinxAPI client.

Can just use mysqli :) Same way it opens a connect to database, open a second connection to sphinx.

Comment: I do get the twice thing . But i dont really wanna do those updates/deletes/inserts twice. So i would like to go with `ATTACH` thing but seems like theres a problem. See my updated question please @barryhunter

Comment: Attach is a one off opperation, just converts an index between types. Just helps with initial commissioning of index. Saves having to build a 'bulk' insert scriptbto get going. Still need to 'maintain' the index, inserting new data, and updating modifed documents etc. Updates are not automatic, attach does not help wirh that